# Increment button not working

Tags: increment

Js

```
//Called when application is started.
function OnStart()
{
// Set counter default to zero
var $counter = 0;

function increase()
{
$counter++;
return false;
 }};
```

Html

```
 <div id="counter">0</div>

<img src="Chop.png" alt="some_text" id="chopper">
<img src="monster1.png" alt="mon" id="monster1">
<img src="shot.png" alt="bang" id="shot">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" id="fire" onClick="counter++;"><p>123</p>
```

I'm just trying to make a basic increment button really can't see what's going wrong as no error messages are coming up.

I'm basically trying to make a very basic html game where you use a button to fire and therefore take -1 from a monster life...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the content of the div with the id "counter", you have to call `document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = <new_value>`

```
<script>
function onStart() 
{ 
    counter = 0; 
} 

function increase() 
{ 
    counter++; 
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter; 
}  
</script> 

<div id="counter">0</div> 

<img src="Chop.png" alt="some_text" id="chopper"> 
<img src="monster1.png" alt="mon" id="monster1">
<img src="shot.png" alt="bang" id="shot"> 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" id="fire" onclick="increase();"><p>123</p>
```

Comment: That's great thanks, but I'm getting a NaN code from the counter, is this because it's referenced in html and JS?

Comment: Maybe because you sometimes used `$counter` instead of `counter`? The dollar sign is not needed here.